# Global Exception Handler implementation C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns

Im trying to implement a global "try catch block" and keep my app running after handling any:

```
public class GlobalExceptionHandler
{
    public GlobalExceptionHandler()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
    }
    private void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            throw (e.ExceptionObject as Exception);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Problems:

1. I expected to handle all exceptions in a familiar way with a `try` `catch` block. Am i doing smth wrong by rethrowing them to catch?
2. The code above still drops the app with an exception popup in the place exception was originally thrown like it has not been handled.
3. Guess my approach is a complete fail from the start. I wanted to avoid using a lot of `try` `catch` blocks through the whole app and decided to localize all exceptions handling. How good this idea is? Should i find a better way to implement a global handler or stick to dozens of `try` `catch` blocks?

Comment: Handling unexpected exceptions should not be very cumbersome. It sounds like there may be an issue with validation in the rest of your code if you have lots of `try/catch` blocks. If you validate arguments in public methods and then handle expected exceptions (that you know how to recover from), then you should let any other exceptions bubble up so you know what they are and can add logic to handle them.

Comment: An empty `catch` block will swallow all exceptions, so when you `throw` from the `try` and then swallow the exception in the `catch`, nothing will happen.

Comment: 1. I want to handle expected ones too. And then set a notification in status bar component depending on what type of exception happened. All that in one place.

2. App crashes on the exception that arrives to handler, not on the rethrowed one inside the handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

windows forms have separate `event` for handling exceptions on GUI thread (ie exceptions which occur on GUI events like button click, textbox text change, etc..):

```
Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Handler);
    
public void Handler(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs t)
{
        //exceptions handling code here...
        

        // you can throw exception at the end of method if you want this exception to go unhandled, not writing throw will swallow exception
        /// throw t.Exception
}
```